# Clickonce - winforms app deployed in shared folder

Tags: c#, winforms

I have been using a shared folder to run a Winforms app.
I read about "ClickOnce" deployment so the app can be downloaded to the client's machine.

If I want to update the software.
It seems easy with "ClickOnce" to tell the client to update before starting.

But if his computer always runs this app without closing it?
Is it possible to enforce him to have the most updated version even if he still uses it?

Thanks.

Comment: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/visualstudio/deployment/how-to-manage-updates-for-a-clickonce-application?view=vs-2022

Answer (score 0):

Set a timer behind the screen.

The timer should check the version in a certain interval for example every 5 mins.

If the new version is available, prompt users to get new version and halt users to use the current program.

Remarks: Version could be in a database.